# SSH to VirtualBox Mac Host Linux Guest using NAT

Tags: macos, network, ssh, virtualbox

How to configure ssh OS X host with Linux guest, so I can access my guest OS through SSH. I've tried:

[image: virtualbox guest]

But when I tried to ssh from host, it failed:

```
> ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

I've tried to set the ip (host 10.0.0.10, guest 10.0.2.15) on the `port forwarding`, it gives the same output. 
I've tried to bind the host to higher address (2222), but got no luck, the host still doesn't listen on port forwarding port.
It doesn't work like this answer: [VirtualBox Host ssh to Guest](https://superuser.com/a/507703/163119)

I could not even ping the guest from the host:

```
PING 10.0.2.15 (10.0.2.15): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
^C
--- 10.0.2.15 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

But ping works fine from guest to host, ssh from guest to localhost is also ok, the `PermitRootLogin` is `yes`, the `netstat` result is ok:

[image: netstat guest]

*EDIT* after switching to bridged mode, it works fine.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve! Your first attempt forwards any host-vb:22 to guest:22 from the host's network. This means you can't reach host from other hosts in the host-vb network (probably 10.0.0.0/24). Is this your aim?

Comment: I want to ssh to my guest OS, i've tried without port forwarding, it failed, with port forwarding also failed, but when I switch to bridged mode it works fine.

Comment: Unless you were running VirtualBox as a privileged user it shouldn't allow you to use host's port 22. You should use a higher number like in the example you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

After adding a port-forwarding rule (e.g. `SSH TCP 10.0.0.10 2222 10.0.2.15 22`) enter in the host's Terminal.app:

```
 ssh user_name@host-ip -p forwarded_port
```

Example with the rule above:

```
 ssh user_name@10.0.0.10 -p 2222
```

Don't use identical ports in the rule (host's port ≠ guest's port) like in your screenshot. *user_name* has to be the name of a remote access enabled account on the guest OS.

You may even skip the IP addresses (10.0.0.10 and 10.0.2.15) in the rule and either use:

```
 ssh user_name@10.0.0.10 -p 2222
```

or

```
 ssh user_name@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

or even

```
 ssh user_name@localhost -p 2222
```

Comment: Please disregard the edit that I made anonymously, which noted that one may also use: `ssh user_name@localhost -p 2222`